# Info icon inside the tags?

Tags: ux-field, ux-designer, tags

I'm working on a popup screen. We've got a budget calculator within. After calculating, the results will be generated. I opted to present the findings in a tag model, which consists of a number, a label, and an information icon. Icon to indicate what it represents. Is it okay to insert the symbol within the Tags? Please look at the picture attached below.[image]

Comment: I don't think those capsules are the best elements for displaying this information. I thought they were buttons when I first opened this.

You're better off just sticking to a list. They're easily readable and good for semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Without having the whole context, it seems a little weird to me to put something as important as a result in a tag, usually more dedicated for filters, status...

But again, i don't know the context. Other than that, I think it's okay to put an information symbol.

Other options would be cards (one for each price) instead of tags and "See more" option instead of info.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer your question - yes, it's OK to include icons within tags / chips / lozenges. In fact the Google Material Design UI includes that very thing. They have ticks, calendar icons, close icons and others included in their tags ('chips' as Google call them).

https://m3.material.io/components/chips/overview

[image]

You can see similar ones in use, including with actual interactive elements within the chips if you do a Google Search (The 'More' chip contains an Actions icon that is interactive and triggers a dropdown when selected):

[image]

**Now, just because it's OK to include icons in your chips, that doesn't necessarily mean the use of chips in this particular situation is correct though.**